# PL/SQL numeric or value error

Tags: plsql

I am quite new to PL/SQL and I am having trouble with the following query:

```
    set serveroutput on
     DECLARE
     result number(10):=0;
     acc number(10);
      BEGIN
      acc:='&Insert_account:';
      for i in 1..9 loop
       result:=(result + (mod(acc,10)*i));
       acc:=trunc(acc/10);
      END LOOP;
      if mod(result,11)=0 then
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Valid number');
      else
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid number');
      END IF;
      END;
```

The account number has 9 digits.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
 Error report -
 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
 ORA-06512: at line 5 06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
```

Comment: You are putting a string into a variable declared as number

Comment: Damn, didn't see that one.Thank you!

Comment: Please avoid using `&` to bind a variable in pl sql. use of `&` is an exclusive feature of SQL*Plus thus, it has no meaning in using it in PL/SQL. It may work on an anonymous block but eventually if converted to a stored procedure or function, it will mean nothing. Use `:` instead.Cheers

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  acc number(10);
  -- ...
  acc := '&Insert_account:' ;
```

Don't see any problem ? XD

So yes, as PL-SQL is typed, you can't put a sting in a variable you declare as a number.

Comment: @MonicaS don't forget to flag as solved your question if it's ok ;)